# seting background color of a list view item dynammically and load different layout row for each item in list view

Tags: android, image, android-listview, bitmap

i have a custom list view which is two buttons , one image view and three text vies inside it. two buttons are "Done" and "Delete"

now i want to change the background color of the one item only when i press Done button.

eg : if i press the done button in the first raw, the raw background should change.
     if i press the done button in 3rd row, that row background also should be changed.

how can i do this ? below is my getview method

```
public View getView(final int position,  final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View vi = convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_for_appoinments,null);




        final TextView firstname = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.first_name);
        final TextView lastname = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.last_name);
        final TextView startTime = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.start_time);
        final TextView endTime = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.end_time);
        final TextView date = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.empty_field);
        final TextView hidID = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.row_id_pationt);
        final TextView hidAppid = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.appoinment_id_row);

         img = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);


        HashMap<String, String> song = data.get(position);

        firstname.setText(song.get("FirstName"));

        //Log.w("viewFirstName", firstName.toString());


        lastname.setText(song.get("LastName"));
        startTime.setText(song.get("StartTime"));
        endTime.setText(song.get("EndTime"));
        date.setText(song.get("Date"));
        hidID.setText(song.get("PersonId"));
        //Log.w("viewhidID", hidID.getText().toString());
        hidAppid.setText(song.get("AppointmentId"));



         theUrl = song.get("ImageURL");




        if(theUrl==null || theUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("") || theUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            Bitmap bImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.propic);
            img.setImageBitmap(bImage);

        }
        else{

            if (cancelPotentialDownload(theUrl, img)) {

                 BitmapDownloaderTask2 task = new BitmapDownloaderTask2(img);
                 DownloadedDrawable2 downloadedDrawable = new DownloadedDrawable2(task);
                 img.setImageDrawable(downloadedDrawable);
                 task.execute(theUrl);
             }


        }

        /*ImageButton direction = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.direction);
        direction.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(mContext, "under construction", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        */



        vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String getPname = hidID.getText().toString();

                Intent zoom=new Intent(parent.getContext(), Profile.class);  
                zoom.putExtra("PatientID", getPname);
                parent.getContext().startActivity(zoom);



            }
        });



        Button btnDone =  (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnDone);
        btnDone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            // here i want to change the background of the row

            }
        });
        return vi;
}
```

and my next problem is , how can i load different layouts for different rows. please help me with code samples , ideas....

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd do is keep track on the adapter for which indices the button has been pressed (using a list of booleans or something). On the `onClick` of the `btnDone`, you'd have to toggle the boolean for that index (which you have in the '`position`' variable) and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter, this will cause the list to be redrawn. When you're in the `getView()` method, check if the current position is true in the list and set the background color then.

For the different layouts, you can just inflate a different layout in `getView()`. You won't be able to reuse the convertView though...

---

**Sample to keep track of views with done button clicked**

In your Adapter, keep a `SparseBooleanArray` variable and add the following method:

```
private void toggleDoneClicked(int position){
    if(doneClickedTrackerArray.get(position)){
        doneClickedTrackerArray.delete(position);
    }else {
        doneClickedTrackerArray.put(position, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Added a code sample. Add this method to your adapter together with a variable of type SparseBooleanArray which you'll have to instantiate in the constructor of your adapter. Next, call toggleDoneClicked from your onClick of the done button and after that call notifyDataSetChanged() and the listview will be redrawn.

Comment: if you can provide me some tutorials please ?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/toonborgers/AutoSMS/blob/master/AutoSMS/src/main/java/be/borgers/autosms/SMSEntryAdapter.java) is an example from something I made. The selection variable is an array which I use to keep track of selected items. on line 86-90 I use this to set the background color on the row.